# Connection fail in end user browser after disable weak ciphers and lower tls version in windows server

Tags: windows-server-2016, tripledes, cbc-mode, rc4-cipher, tls1.0

First I disable the following things in windows server 2016.

- Triple DES cipher
- RC4 cipher
- TLS CBC Mode ciphers
- TLS 1.0
- TLS 1.1

Then, I reboot the server.
Finally, I call the web application which is hosted at above server from my client browser.
Here is the problem `I can not connect to that web application via browser`
What am I missing something?
What should I do to be able to use from end users?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just turn off the windows server firewall to be able to connection from client site.
It works for me. It's not affected due to disability of above ciphers and tls.